# Can Compass generate sprites from images in folders outside of app/assets/images"? Like in lib/assets/images or even Gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, compass-sass

I was under the impression that Compass could generate sprites from image files in a Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline environment; however, I can't get it to work.

In my application.scss file I have the following code:

```
@import "foo/*.png";
@include all-foo-sprites;
```

If I have the `foo` directory in `app/assets/images`, this works just fine, but if I have it in `lib/assets/images` or `vender/assets/images` it doesn't work at all.

I keep getting the error:

```
No files were found in the load path matching "foo/*.png". Your current load paths are: /Users/xxxxxx/app/assets/images
```

But I know that `vender/assets/images/foo` **is** in the load path because `image-url('foo/bar.png')` works just fine.

What I'd **really** like is to have the images in a Gem (since they're shared across many of my apps), but I can't get that to work either.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I know compass-rails supports the asset pipeline, but I can't find anywhere that mentions support for this specific feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like by default compass-rails doesn't look for sprites in the normal assets pipeline directories which isn't what I expected but it can be easily added if you want it.

I just added the following code in a compass initializer which basically adds all of the asset pipeline load paths to Compass's sprite_load_path.

```
Compass.add_configuration({:sprite_load_path => Compass.configuration.sprite_load_path + Rails.application.config.assets.paths}, 'sprites')
```